# Antivirus Showing My C# Win Form App As IDP.Generic Virus

Tags: c#

I am working on a desktop app related to chat And antivirus is showing it as virus.
I have read other forms regarding this problem and provided the AssemblyInfo but still not working.

My Program Does Fllowing Things:

It opens a web socket connection whenever it runs so that it could notify that message recieve.
It also enable itself to run on startup through registry.
It also checks for some dll files required for software if exist using File.exist
It also perform some system actions through Process.start

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. Your post does not contain a question. Please [edit] your post to include a question and your attempts so far on how to solve it.

Comment: All of the things your program does are exactly what a virus would do.   I'm guessing that your program is NOT using an installer application to add itself to the startup registry?